# Android Keyboard is not showing on click / on focus / requestFocus / inputmanager show_forced

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

I got an problem with the android soft keyboard. Sometimes the keyboard will not pop up, it looks like the editText doesn't gain focus. The Cursor is set and blinking, but the border of the editText doesn't change (normally blue or orange on focus).

The rest of the application is running fine, but every editText is stuck. I tried to execute requestFocus() (returns true) and to show the Keyboard via InputManager while debugging or with a onFocuschange- and onClickListener. No changes. I am sure that the correct editText has the focus of the window (getCurrentFocus()).
I can't imagine that this is a memory problem, because the GC logs, that 15-30% are free.

I can't post any code, because the application is really huge and the problem appears "randomly", without any error logs or exceptions.

Thanks for any Advice =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. the inputManager activeElement was a closed dialog, the solution is to call looper.quit() at the correct moment.